# New Mac has 3 battery cycles

Tags: macbook-pro, mac

I bought a new MacBook Pro 13-inch M1 3 days ago from the Apple Store.

Now I see that it has 3 cycle counts. I charged it only one time for around 60%.

Why?
Is it normal?

Answer (score 3):

Three cycles could be explained with

- One load cycle after the battery was manufactured (as part of the testing)
- One load cycle before the Mac leaves the factory (to make sure you can just boot it up when you get it)
- One you did yourself

but we have no easy way of knowing whether this is correct. Nevertheless I would probably only be worried if the cycle count of a new battery is higher than 10.

Comment: Exactly! Three cycles is compared to the lifetime of such a battery basically nothing. They are designed to last 1000 cycles, therefore 3 more or less won't make any difference. +1

Comment: Yeah, this is similar to miles on a car. You might have grounds to complain or at least enquire if your new car had 100 or 200 miles – but this is like asking why it has 5 miles on the odometer.